# how to set launch activity for Google Play or APK installer

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-install-apk

I have the follow manifest part about application

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_goodrider_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/PingTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".passenger.ui.LicenseActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_passenger_label" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_logo"
        android:taskAffinity="com.city.passenger"            
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".driver.ui.LicenseActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_driver_label" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_logo"
        android:taskAffinity="com.city.driver"            
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and I want to set launch activity for Google Play Open button (visible after install) or APK install Open button.

Is it possible with out one more launch icon at apps?

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <activity android:name=".FirstLaunchActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the `Open` button after the APK was installed is grayed out (disabled) when there are multiple main activities in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Interestingly enough, it seems that this is only the case for pre-ICS devices. In Ice Cream Sandwich, the `Open` button is clickable and the first `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` with an `android.intent.action.MAIN` intent filter will be opened on tap.

Comment: Yep... Maybe you right. I have exactly the pre-ICS device (API 11).